# Cannot load library jni ffmpeg in intellij idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ffmpeg

After a lot of trial and error I managed to make all the program work except when coming to load a library. The library is located in the JNI folder. Can someone help me with this error?

`02-11 21:38:32.940  26771-26771/com.example.untitled E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.untitled, PID: 26771
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load nativetester-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.untitled-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.untitled-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at com.example.untitled.NativeTester.<clinit>(NativeTester.java:23)
            at com.example.untitled.FFmpegPlayer.<clinit>(FFmpegPlayer.java:184)
            at com.example.untitled.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.java:134)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Answer (score 1):

The library should not be in the JNI folder, only your source. The actual library should be in the `libs/armeabi`, and should be named in your case `libnativetester-jni.so`

Comment: but the library is named nativetester.c not .so. any recommendations?

Comment: You did not build the library then, you only have the source code for the library.

Comment: Yes, with NDK, Check the NDK docs, and ask if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

[For More Clear Clarification have a look at Image :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikK4H.png)

Try this:
add following in your build.gradle (module:app)
ndk {
moduleName "nativetester-jni"
}

Answer (score 0):

The below link is a perfectly working demo.
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html
Please follow step which is mentioned in above link.
Because i already implemented video compression and making video by merging images using above link.
Hope it will help you out.

Comment: This does not provide answer to the question. It should possibly be an a comment.

Comment: can you just tell me what kind of functionality you want to implement by using ffmpeg ?,so i can guide you exactly.